# Is this symmetric, block-diagonal matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

I have a matrix of the following form, where $a,b,c>0$
\begin{align*}
 A = \left[
 \begin{array}{cccccc}
 aM_{12}^2 & aM_{12}M_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 aM_{13}M_{12} & aM_{13}^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & bM_{21}^2 & bM_{21}M_{23} & bM_{21}M_{24} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & bM_{23}M_{21} & bM_{23}^2 & bM_{23}M_{24} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & bM_{24}M_{21} & bM_{24}M_{23} & bM_{24}^2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & cM_{31}^2 & cM_{31}M_{32} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & cM_{32}M_{31} & cM_{32}^2
 \end{array}
 \right]
\end{align*}
Is this matrix positive semi-definite? Since it is block-diagonal, I am thinking that it should be easy to check something to do with determinants, but I'm not sure how to write it out. Also, can the above matrix be written in a more concise fashion?

*Update*:

Is it sufficient to check that the all leading principal minors (from Wiki: "the kth leading principal minor of a matrix A is the determinant of its upper-left k by k sub-matrix") of the sub-matrices are non-negative?

Comment: The determinant of a block diagonal matrix is the product of their blocks determinants ([source][1]). Not sure how that would help, though. What is the process that creates this matrix?

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices

Comment: Thank you. This matrix is actually the first part of a sum (of two parts) of the Hessian of a function composition of the form $\sum_{i=1}^m f(g_i(A_i^T{\bf x}))$ (not very inspiring, if I can ensure this is positive semi-definite, I can make a statement regarding the convexity of the function).

Comment: It think it is obvious that the matrix is sp(semi)d iff the three blocks are, and that we can therefore drop the constants $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: Are any of the $M$ matrices symmetric?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, the $M_{ij}$ components are scalars (elements of a matrix $M$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first block, which is of the form $C = [\alpha^2 \ \alpha \beta; \alpha \beta \ \beta^2]$. Let $z = [x; y]$ be a column $2$-vector. Then: $z' C z = [\alpha x; \beta y]' [1 \ 1; 1 \ 1] [\alpha x; \beta y] \geq 0$, because the matrix $[1 \ 1; 1 \ 1]$ is sp(semi)d. The same happens with the $3\times3$ block. Therefore, your matrix is sp(semi)d.

Comment: Could I relax the assumption that $a,b,c>0$ and instead just assume that $a,b,c\ge0$? This will cause some of the matrices to potentially be zero matrices, but I suppose the result still holds? Thanks!

Comment: yes. you will have a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. (which means $x' A x \geq 0$ for all vectors $x$ of compatible size; and if you zero out one of the diagonal blocks, you can just as well drop the corresponding components of $x$).